# Searching for specific files on a device

Tags: java, android, file, search

I'm a newcomer to mobile programming and want to start off with a little Musicplayer-App. I need to search for all files which end with .mp3, .m4a, .wav, and so on. To do this, I want to first get a list of all files and then filter out the audio-files.

However, when I use getExternalStorageDirectory to get the path to the storage it returns "/storage/3139-6333", which is obviously not correct.

**Basically I'm just curious why I get this result and how to fix it.**

It's to be assumed that READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is permitted.
Thanks in advance.

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if ((Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)||Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)))
{
    File sd_card = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); //"/storage/3139-6333"
    File[] listFile = sd_card .listFiles(); //null
}
```

Comment: Did you asked `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to use user's SD card? (You should add it to your `manifest.xml` too)

Comment: @Nofix My question was pretty whacky overall, I hope I managed to improve it.

Comment: The storage name you are getting in return sounds absolutly correct to me. On my device, it is pretty similar.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have the path where you wish to do file search, if yes then you can use basic dfs algorithm to search your desired file.

below is example code for that, you can put any format in end to check all files for it.

```
public void search(String path){

        File file = new File(path);
        File[] files = file.listFiles();

        if (files!=null) {
            for (File f : files) {

                if (f.isDirectory()) {

                    this.search(f.getAbsolutePath());
                }

                if (f.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".txt")) {

                    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
                }

            } 
        }

    }
```

hope this will help.

Comment: I rewrote my question to make it clearer what my interrest is; however, this answer is great for the actual searching!